# Storing XML from SAP in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, xml, csv, dictionary, business-objects

I would like to store this XML in a dictionary, then saving it in a csv :

```
<dataprovider>
    <id>DP1</id>
    <name>Query 1</name>
    <dataSourceId>7599</dataSourceId>
    <dataSourceType>bex</dataSourceType>
    <dataSourcePrefix>DS0</dataSourcePrefix>
    <updated>2012-07-31T15:44:25.000+02:00</updated>    
    <duration>1</duration>
    <isPartial>false</isPartial>
    <rowCount>284</rowCount>
    <flowCount>1</flowCount>
    <dictionary>
        <expression dataType="String" qualification="Dimension">
            <id>DP1.DO1</id>
            <name>City</name>
            <description>City</description>  
            <dataSourceObjectId>AZ_CITY</dataSourceObjectId> 
            <formulaLanguageId>[City]</formulaLanguageId> 
        </expression>  
        <expression dataType="String" qualification="Dimension">
            <id>DP1.DO1d</id> 
            <name>Customer</name>  
            <description>Customer</description>  
            <dataSourceObjectId>AZ_CUSTOM</dataSourceObjectId>  
            <formulaLanguageId>[Query 2].[Customer]</formulaLanguageId> 
        </expression>  
        <expression dataType="String" qualification="Dimension"> 
            <id>DP1.DO6</id>
            <name>Sales Person</name>
            <description>Sales Person</description>
            <dataSourceObjectId>AZ_SALES</dataSourceObjectId>
            <formulaLanguageId>[Query 2].[Sales Person]</formulaLanguageId>
        </expression>  
        <expression dataType="Numeric" qualification="Measure" highPrecision="true"> 
            <id>DP1.DO5c</id> 
            <name>Order Amount</name>
            <description>Order Amount</description> 
            <dataSourceObjectId>MCWZZCK8Z39ES5HKKFA52FG78E</dataSourceObjectId> 
            <formulaLanguageId>[Query 2].[Order Amount]</formulaLanguageId> 
        </expression>  
        <expression dataType="Numeric" qualification="Measure" highPrecision="false"> 
            <id>DP1.DO5f</id>  
            <name>Order Quantity</name>  
            <description>Order Quantity</description>  
            <dataSourceObjectId>M7MRKCICEBY5WYKQ8AL86VY9Q8</dataSourceObjectId>  
            <formulaLanguageId>[Query 2].[Order Quantity]</formulaLanguageId> 
        </expression> 
    </dictionary>
    <query>CgASFQoGWl9DSVRZEgsKB0FaX0NJVFkQARIXCgdaX1NBTEVTEgwKCEFaX1NBTEVTEAES
        GQoIWl9DVVNUT00SDQoJQVpfQ1VTVE9NEAEaSwoZQ1daWkNLOFozOUVTNUhLS0ZBNTJGRzc
        4RRIMT3JkZXIgQW1vdW50GAIiHgoaTUNXWlpDSzhaMzlFUzVIS0tGQTUyRkc3OEUQBhpNCh
        k3TVJLQ0lDRUJZNVdZS1E4QUw4NlZZOVE4Eg5PcmRlciBRdWFudGl0eRgCIh4KGk03TVJLQ
        0lDRUJZNVdZS1E4QUw4NlZZOVE4EAYgACgAMAE=</query>  
</dataprovider>
```

https://help.sap.com/viewer/58f583a7643e48cf944cf554eb961f5b/4.2/en-US/45f8b22d6e041014910aba7db0e91070.html

How can I do that? I'm failing to have :

- DP1 | name | dataSourceId | ... | DP1.DO1  | City | description | ... |
- DP1 | name | dataSourceId | ... | DP1.DO1d | City | description | ... |
- DP1 | name | dataSourceId | ... | DP1.DO6  | City | description | ... |
- DP2 | name | dataSourceId | ... | DP2.DO1  | City | description | ... |

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: why Python tag? is it somehow related to Python? or if this Python dictionary does it really matter from where the XML came from?